# Ebean persistence not working in Play 2.0

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

To familirise myself with the Play 2.0 Framework, I've been following the [Play 2.0 introduction tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTodoList). Unforunatly, I can't get the Ebean persistence to work. My `Task.java` looks like this:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;

import play.db.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id 
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String label;

    public static List<Task> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

    public static void create(Task task) {
        task.save();
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
        find.ref(id).delete();
    }

}
```

But on running the applicaton, `find` and `save` can't be resolved. I guess I forgot to import a module, but I can't figure out which on it is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dan W. already said, you need to extend the `Model` class:

```
@Entity
public class Task extends Model {
    ....
}
```

You also have to add the following static methode:

```
public static Finder<Long,Task> find = new Finder(
    Long.class, Task.class
);
```

Also make sure you added following lines to your `application.conf` file to enable the database:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
ebean.default="models.*"
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe you need to extend `Model` class.

```
@Entity
public class Task extends Model {
    ....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm stupid ... but that dose not seem to work either. I get an error that `Model` can't be found ... I'm confused!

Comment: @wowpatrick Try importing: play.db.ebean.Model and also enable the line "ebean.default="models.*"" in application.conf - Found this at bottom of your provided link.

Comment: I incorrectly thought that `play.db.*` would also include `play.db.ebean.*`. But it still results in the original error ...

Comment: Apparently I'm resistant to advice ... I found the problem and answered the question myself. Thanks for your help & time!

Comment: @wowpatrick If you have solved the problem, you should answer and accept your answer so others can see what you did in case they have a similar problem.